# Datetimepicker Value Changed event not fired when number 12 is inserted

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm having an issue in my Win-Forms program. I added a Value-Changed event to my DateTimePicker as following:

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{Right}");
    }
```

For some reason, when number 12 is inserted, either into day field or into month field, the event is alternately fired. I have tried many other numbers and they all work perfectly. To whom may finds it relevant, the date format is dd/MM/yyyy. Is it a known issue?

EDIT:
Just to be clear, all numbers from 1 to 31 (except to 12, of course) in day field fire it, as well as all numbers from 1-11 in month field

Comment: So you're saying the event fires for any other value (single digit, 10, 11, etc.) ? It seems very awkward to not fire for number 12

Comment: Hehe, yes indeed. Any other digits fire it like a charm

Comment: Well, the only weird thing I notice is that we are in the 12th month. So it might be somehow related to that. The event might not fire value changed on entering 12 in the month field because it is already the 12th month and the datetimepicker is initialized by default to DateTime.Now . However, this theory does not apply for the day field since it's 22... You should post more of the code, especially the part where you register to the event, because it's difficult to spot anything with only this amount of information

Comment: I thought exactly the same. I changed the default value to 1/1/2014 for instance, still the same problem

Comment: One's first reaction is that this is some kind of April fools joke? If not, what other event handlers do you have for this control? What properties (setup options) have you specified? Is there a visual difference when you enter 12 and when you enter other numbers? Is the control bound to a datasource? Have you tried adding another DateTimePicker to your form and seeing if it has the same behavior?

Comment: I wish it were a joke. There are no other handlers for this control. There is no difference when I enter 12 and when I enter any other number, unfortunately. The control is not bound to any datasource. In addition, there are many DateTimePickers in my application and ALL of them have the same issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't care to theorize too much about the cause of this behavior, you didn't document the question well enough to guess at an accurate answer.  DateTimePicker is a "tricky" control and trying to hack it is almost never not a mistake.  Microsoft tinkers it a lot, it is used in two *highly* visible places in Windows, both at install time to let the user calibrate the clock and in the clock widget on the taskbar.  Strong look-and-feel places.  You didn't mention your Windows version.

But the most obvious flaw in your approach is that you can *never* make it reliable.  The ValueChanged event will of course only fire when the date actually changed.  If it didn't, because the user entered a day or month that already matches the Value property then you don't get the event.  So a trivial explanation is that you initialized it to December 12th.  You didn't mention the initial value.

There is nothing you can do to avoid this problem, DTP doesn't support a "null" date that guarantees that the event will always fire.  There is no "the user is done typing" event.  The advice here is the one my doctor tends to fall back on: if it hurts then don't do it.  If that hurts then make your own control.

Comment: As you said, I misunderstood the control's behavior. I did type the same number as it was before, and that's why it wasn't fired. Kinda stupid, I should have read the actual event's name, value-CHANGE, and mine wasn't changed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you have provided the issue is not reproducible. Probably you are missing something.

Adding a simple Datetimepicker control on Winform and changing its values is continuously calling the value changed event.

See the below image:

**When date changed to 11 then textbox is updated to 11**

[image: When date changed to 11 then textbox is updated to 11]

**On changing the date to 12 the textbox is updated to 12**

[image: On changing the date to 12 the textbox is updated to 12]

Here is the code for updating the textbox

```
private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Value.Day.ToString;
}
```

You can add a new form in your application and test it, I am sure its going to work fine. Then you can try to find out what's going wrong in your actual application.

Comment: I made a new project, added a dateTimePicker, and your code. I'm surprised to say that I'm facing the same issue in the new project with a fresh new dateTimePicker(!)